# Document XML data Sharepoint 2010 Silverlight

Tags: xml, silverlight, sharepoint, xml-serialization

I have a document libraries where I save documents (je). (from silverlight too, but that problem is already solved)

I want to use the object model of Sharepoint 2010 from a silverlight application to get the XML data of a document with ID=...

First I serialize a class and upload to the document library and then I want to get it...

That XML must contain an object to deserialize with XMLSerializer...

How can I do it?

Comment: Please provide more information on what you're trying to accomplish.  I think you're saying you want a Silverlight application to access items within your SharePoint Document Library.  Is this correct?

Comment: You'll only be able to deserialize data if the data in the document library was already serialized. Please give more info.

Comment: Yeah, first I serialize a class and upload to the document library and then I want to get it, thats the point, yeah @Robert Williams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it first:

```
  using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://med02ws:47205/Documentos"))
                {
                    Web web = ctx.Web;

                    List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(tipo);

                    DocumentoObtenidoSP = docs.GetItemById(id);

                    ctx.Load(DocumentoObtenidoSP);
                    ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync(OnCargarDocumentoSucceess, OnSharepointFailure);
                }

     private void OnCargarDocumentoSucceess(object sender, ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs e)
{
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(WebClient_OpenFileReadCompleted);
                wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://med02ws:47205" + DocumentoObtenidoSP.FieldValues["FileRef"].ToString()));
}

private void WebClient_OpenFileReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
//In e.Result you got the stream to XML Deserialize using the XMLSerializer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you'll want to get acquainted with the Silverlight Client Object Model, here's a starter, but there's quite a few others out there:

http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2010/03/sharepoint-2010-silverlight-client.html

Then you'll want to find oout how to query a list using CAML, and using the items in your resultset to get the Document in the library you're after.

You'll probably then want to stream the contents (using SPListItem.File.OpenBinaryStream()) into a reader of some sort so you can deserialize.

Comment: I'm in the silverlight so SPListItem is not available :(

Comment: It will be available if you use the silverlight client object model to get it. Have a look at this: http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/2010/11/04/how-to-access-sharepoint-list-items-using-silverlight-object-model/. I should add the object is caledd "ListItem" rather than "SPListItem" - that's one of the main differences between the server and client object models in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good set of information regarding the SharePoint Client Object Model:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx

Here is a specific example of how to query a list (e.g. Document Library) with the Client Object Model:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx#SP2010ClientOM_Using_CAML_Query_List

I really like this example on the .NET by Example site:

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2011/03/sharepoint-client-object-model-sites.html

I liked the idea of creating the SharePointHelper class as a wrapper for the Client Object Model.  It provides many examples including **"Download a file from a document library"**

Comment: This is all the Client Object Model and nothing abuot Silverlight - the main difference in Silverlight being (apart from a different referenced codebase) is that you cannot do synchronous ExecuteQuery calls with the Client Object Model in Silverlight.

Comment: @JamesLove - I provided my answer with specific examples of the Client Object Model only because it seems to me that Daniel G. R. (who asked the question) already knows their way around Silverlight.  The question seemed to lean more in the SharePoint Client Object Model direction.